# jQuery dynamically increment variable name inside a for-loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, for-loop, count

is it possible to add i to a var inside a for-loop?
in wrong syntax it would look like the code below

```
for(i=1; i<=countProjects; i++){

    var test + i = $(otherVar).something();

};
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should be using an array.

Comment: He wants to increment variable names. That's the question.

Comment: Please elaborate. Increment the variable, or the variable name?

Comment: What you want to do with `test` variable ?

Comment: sorry if I was unclear, the variable name. So if i == 3 you'll get test1, test2 and test3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be best to use an array for this:

```
var test = [];

for (i = 1; i <= countProjects; i++) {
    test[i] = $(otherVar).something();
};
```

Then you could access the values like this:

```
console.log(test[1]);
console.log(test[2]);
etc...
```

If you have really good reason to have named variables for each value, you can create them like this:

```
for (i = 1; i <= countProjects; i++) {
    window["test" + i] = $(otherVar).something();
};

console.log(test1);
```

Comment: `window["test"...]` will only be accessible in global scope, if no scope indication is used on the trace (`console.log(window.test1);`. You shouldn't assume it's always global scope, IMHO.

Answer (score 5):

As [Mat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/635608/mat) stated, you should be using arrays for this type of functionality:

```
var projects = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= countProjects; i++) {
    projects.push($(otherVar).something());
}
```

You could craft variable names, using `object["varname"]` syntax. But it's *_generally_* bad practice:

```
var varName;
for (var i = 0; i <= countProjects; i++) {
    varName = "test" + i.toString();
    this[varName] = $(otherVar).something();
}
console.log(test1);
```